# How I can add both Azure AD and non Azure AD tokens to the same .NET Core Api

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt

Want to do something like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("private_key"))
                };
            })
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(this.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

But it crashes. If I add a name for each scheme, then [Authorize] doesn't work.

How I can do something like this, and distinguish the [Authorize] methods on different controllers for either one or the other?

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Why would you want to distinguish the Authorize methods? In every scenario I can think of you'd want Authorize to be able to check either method so users signed in can use the same controller. Otherwise you'd have to be duplicating controllers.

Answer (score 0):

For AAD use [Authorize] on the controller 
For non AAD then I use [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Other"]

Add the "Other" scheme name to the .AddJwtBearer one as displayed below.

Happy coding :)

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer("Other", options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("private_key"))
                };
            })
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(this.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not enough just to add Authentication you need to configure policy so both will be validated (in [official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-multiple-authentication-schemes) doc)

```
  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
            JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            "AzureAD");
        defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = 
            defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
    });
```